# How to output only the first or all matches in Powershell like `sed`?

Tags: powershell, sed

In `sed` one can output all matches or e.g. only the first:

```bash
$ echo -e 'a1\nb2\nb3'
a1
b2
b3

# print all matches
$ echo -e 'a1\nb2\nb3' | sed -n '/b\(.\)/s//\1/p'
2
3

# print only first match
$ echo -e 'a1\nb2\nb3' | sed -n '0,/b\(.\)/s//\1/p'
2
```

How can I do this with Powershell?

I get only the first match:

```powershell
@'
>> a1
>> b2
>> b3
>> '@ | Select-String 'b(.*)' | ForEach-Object{$_.Matches.Groups[1].Value}
2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Your PowerShell **[here-string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#here-strings) (`@'<newline>...<newline>'@`) is a *single object* (string) that happens to be a *multi-line* string**.
- To [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string), each input object is a "line", and by default it looks only for the *first* match on each "line" - unless you specify the `-AllMatches` switch.

  - Input is *implicitly* line by line only in the following scenarios:

    - Letting `Select-String` itself read and process files with the `-Path` or `-LiteralPath` parameter.
    - Using `Get-Content` output as input, which streams line by line by default (though using `Select-String`'s `-Path` / `-LiteralPath` or piping `Get-ChildItem` output is much more efficient).
    - Piping output from calls to *external programs*, whose stdout output is also streamed line by line.
- With `-AllMatches` present and *more than one object* stored in the [`.Matches`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo.Matches) collection, the [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Member-Access_Enumeration) operation `$_.Matches.Groups[1].Value` is insufficient for obtaining *each* match's `.Groups[1].Value` property - you need to *iterate over* the `$_.Matches` collection and apply `.Groups[1].Value` to each element.

Therefore, to **get *all* matches**:

```
@'
a1
b2
b3
'@ |
  Select-String 'b(.*)' -AllMatches |
  ForEach-Object{ $_.Matches.ForEach({ $_.Groups[1].Value }) }
```

Output:

```
2
3
```

To get **only the *first* match**, your command works as-is, for the reasons explained above.

---

**Alternatively**, you could have **split your here-string into individual lines first**, in which case the rest of your command would have worked as-is to **get *all* matches**:

```
@'
a1
b2
b3
'@ -split '\r?\n' |  # Split the multi-line string into indiv. lines
  Select-String 'b(.*)' |
  ForEach-Object{ $_.Matches.Groups[1].Value }
```

To get **only the *first* match**, with line-by-line output, pipe the above to `Select-Object -First 1`.

Note: `Select-String` has a `-List` switch that looks for at most *one* match, but it only applies to *files* as input, either via its own `-Path` / `-LiteralPath` parameter, or by piping file-info objects from `Get-ChildItem`.